# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 'PHImageContentMode' (aka 'enum PHImageContentMode')

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Why am I getting this error?

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 'PHImageContentMode' (aka 'enum PHImageContentMode')

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager]
requestImageForAsset:asset
targetSize:CGSizeMake(2 * w, 2 * h)
contentMode:nil
options:0
resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info)
{
    imgView.image = result;
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contentMode` parameter requires an `enum` parameter, but you are passing `nil` which is a `void pointer`.

Replace `nil` with `0` for enums:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager]
requestImageForAsset:asset
targetSize:CGSizeMake(2 * w, 2 * h)
contentMode:0
options:0
resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info)
{
  imgView.image = result;
}];
```